# htaccess rewrite except one parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make some url rewrite with `htaccess`,

```
http://www.example.com/article.php?post_id=123&title=2014-03-02-today-s-trends
=>
http://www.example.com/article/123/2014-03-02-today-s-trends
```

but some special rule. if some article click from rss or social share. I want to:

```
http://www.example.com/article.php?post_id=123&title=2014-03-02-today-s-trends&source=rss
=>
http://www.example.com/article/123/2014-03-02-today-s-trends?source=rss
```

my rewrite code here

```
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/(.*)\?source=(.*)?$ article.php?post_id=$1&title=$2&source=$3
```

but get 500 error. How to do it in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `QSA` flag so that it will append the query string with it if `source=rss` is on the URL.

Not sure how your ogininal rewrite is but you can try this. It should work with or without `source=rss`

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)/(.+)$ article.php?post_id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Then in your code you can check for the `source` key in the $_GET.